# When trying to run "Truffle Develop" i get the below error message.....Anyone have any solutions?

Tags: truffle, truffle-develop

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at hash160 (/mnt/c/Users/joeda/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/ethereum-cryptography/vendor/hdkey-without-crypto.js:249:1)
    at HDKey.set (/mnt/c/Users/joeda/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/ethereum-cryptography/vendor/hdkey-without-crypto.js:50:1)
    at Function.HDKey.fromMasterSeed (/mnt/c/Users/joeda/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/ethereum-cryptography/vendor/hdkey-without-crypto.js:194:1)
    at Function.fromMasterSeed (/mnt/c/Users/joeda/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/ethereumjs-wallet/dist/hdkey.js:19:1)
    at Object.getAccountsInfo (/mnt/c/Users/joeda/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/mnemonics/mnemonic.js:48:1)
    at Object.module.exports [as run] (/mnt/c/Users/joeda/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/develop/run.js:39:1)
    at runCommand (/mnt/c/Users/joeda/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command-utils.js:190:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The LTS version of Node has changed recently. It's possible that it has bumped your version of Node silently.

According to [GitHub issue (#5511)](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/5511), Truffle does not support v17 or v18. I reckon you most probably use a version that is not supported.

Steps to resolve:

1. Downgrade node to v16
2. Downgrade npm to v6
3. Run `npm install` again

*Note: There could be other incompatible dependencies in your setup. ie. `react-scripts` had similar issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported). The solution to similar issues is usually to find the correct version.*